# Sort Java ArrayList with Letters before numbers

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist

I am currently passing in an ArrayList to populate the titles of a TabLayout in Android. The elements in the array are strings: `["RCP", "RYL", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"].` Yet, not necessarily in that order.

I would like the list to be returned with the Letter elements first (alphabetically) and then integers rising, incrementally.

I have tried using the `Collections.sort` method, but this returns a list the rises numerically and then adds the "R" strings last: `["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "RCP", "RYL"]`

To clarify, I would like to sort my ArrayList, so that it returns `["RCP", "RYL", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]` It also needs to be flexible, as the titles of the "R", strings, are likely to change.

Thanks

Comment: Custom comparator might work.

Comment: Are the integers also likely to change? Might you have 2 or more-digit numbers at some point of time and want "9" to appear before "10" in the result?

Comment: The integers are likely to be suffixed with a string value. I.e. `["1AB", "1AV"]`. Which would then need to print in order of String prefix first, then numerical prefix after i.e. `["RCA", "RLM", "1EP", "1FT", "2LJ", "2MO"]` So on and so forth. I haven't checked for this yet...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to give priority to strings that represents numbers over strings that do not, you should consider writing your own `Comparator` and pass it to the `Collections.sort` method.

This is a simple approach to your problem: check if any of the strings is a number, if so, give priority to the string that is not a number. If both are numbers or strings, use string's `compareTo` method.

Hope it helps.

```
public class Main {

    private static int customCompare(String a, String b) {
        return isThereAnyNumber(a, b)
                ? isNumber(a) ? 1 : -1
                : a.compareTo(b);
    }

    private static boolean isThereAnyNumber(String a, String b) {
        return isNumber(a) || isNumber(b);
    }

    private static boolean isNumber(String s) {
        return s.matches("[-+]?\\d*\\.?\\d+");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("RCP", "RYL", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6");
        Collections.sort(list, Main::customCompare);
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

You can use an anonymous inner class that implements the `Comparator` interface in case you're not using Java 8.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("RCP", "RYL", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6");
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
            private boolean isThereAnyNumber(String a, String b) {
                return isNumber(a) || isNumber(b);
            }

            private boolean isNumber(String s) {
                return s.matches("[-+]?\\d*\\.?\\d+");
            }

            @Override
            public int compare(String a, String b) {
                return isThereAnyNumber(a, b)
                        ? isNumber(a) ? 1 : -1
                        : a.compareTo(b);
            }
        });
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I can't call `Collections.sort(list, Main::customCompare);` in Android though, it throws: "Method references are not supported at this language level". Any ideas?

Comment: @dantan04 I've provided a new solution that doesn't make use of lambdas in case you're not using Java 8 or in Android some things I used (like method references) are not supported. Hope it works now.

Comment: This helps a lot! I have created this via: 

`Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String s, String t1) {
                customCompare(s, t1);
                return 0;
            }
        });`

Which returns the list: `["6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1", "R"]` I just need that to be reversed now, is there a method for that?

Comment: @dantan04 The problem in your snippet is that your compare method returns 0, it should be returning the result of customCompare. So, you should replace the two lines that you have in the body of the compare method to `return customCompare(s, t1);` Hope that solves your problem

Answer (score 4):

There is an overload for [`Collections.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-) which will take in a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), which will allow you to define the sort order for your items.  In this case, all you have to do is define your own implementation of the `Comparator` interface which does as you please.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just reading up on the `Comparator` documentation now. (I'm currently learning android from a good book, so it's steady progress).